# PHP list multiple value into array

Tags: php, list

I have a hotel database which has multiple rates due to the room types. I'd like to list it dynamically into array (of each room type) accordingly. My data structures are:

- Hotel A : 1200-1500-1300-1700 //room type 1=1200usd/night, room type 2=1500usd/night ...
- Hotel B : 1500-1200-1300
- Hotel C : 800-850

And I'd like to list it into each room type. So I wrote:

```
while($rec = mysql_fetch_array($result_rate)) {  
    $_roomId = $rec['rid'];
    $_roomRate = $rec['rate'];

    list($ratez[]) = explode("-", $_rate); //because the room type is varied by hotel so I make it in array
}
```

So I expect the result should comes up like

```
echo "Room ID $_roomId=$ratez[$_roomId] USD ";
```

But the result is not as I expect. It keeps displaying error `Fatal error: Unsupported operand types.`

Comment: `list` does not work like that. Also, this code has 6 different variables all of which are used *only once*???

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$ratez[] = explode('-', $_rate);
```

Or this to save rates for each room:

```
$ratez[$_roomId] = explode('-', $_rate);
```

Comment: This is what I'm talking about @Night2. But still, I have an error : Fatal error: Unsupported operand types.

Comment: Change your echo to this: 


`echo 'Room ID '.$_roomId.'='.$ratez[$_roomId][0].' USD';` 

Inplace of [0] you can loop the array and use the right index.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is just:

```
$_rCostz=explode("-",$rec['cost']);
```

and echo the result in currency format as :

```
echo number_format($_rCostz[$room_id-1])
```

//because the room id starts with 1 but the array begins` with "0" so -1

Thank you very much, Night2 and others. Problem solved.